# Conditional template inheritance does not work in Symfony 4

Tags: twig, extends, symfony4

I want a template to inherit a base template when user is not logged in and other template when user is logged in.

I tried several things. One of the obvious is this attempt:

```
{% extends app.user == null ? 'base.html.twig' : 'protected.html.twig' %}
```

Other attempt:

```
{% extends app.user ? 'protected.html.twig' : 'base.html.twig' %}
```

And so on... nothing works. Always base.html.twig is used.

When I display {{ app.user }} value, the correct value is shown (username or empty if logged in or not logged in, respectively)

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is the full template I need to be conditional, depending if the user is logged in or not.

```
{% extends app.user ? 'protected.html.twig' : 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Inicio{% endblock %}

{% block conditional %}  
    <style>
        .example-wrapper { margin: 1em auto; max-width: 800px; width: 95%; font: 18px/1.5 sans-serif; }
        .example-wrapper code { background: #F5F5F5; padding: 2px 6px; }
    </style>
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <h1>Hello {{ controller_name }}! ✅</h1>

        This friendly message is coming from:
        <ul>
            <li>Your controller at <code><a href="{{ 'src/Controller/DefaultController.php'|file_link(0) }}">src/Controller/DefaultController.php</a></code></li>
            <li>Your template at <code><a href="{{ 'templates/default/index.html.twig'|file_link(0) }}">templates/default/index.html.twig</a></code></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% if app.user %}
    {% block protected_body %}
        {{ block('conditional') }}
    {% endblock %}
{% else %}
     {% block body %}
        {{ block('conditional') }}
    {% endblock %}   
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am sure that it is not possible. Maybe a limitation of twig.

So, I have added that condition in controller and render a template or other depending on the user.

Inside both templates, I added an include to a common template.

Regards,
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `if` inside the `block`, because conditionals blocks are not a thing in `twig`

```
{% block protected_body %}
    {% if app.user %}
        {{ block('conditional') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
 {% block body %}
    {% if not app.user %}
        {{ block('conditional') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```